# gradle init does not work for some plugin in pom.xml

Tags: maven, gradle

> It seems gradle init does not work for some plugin in pom.xml
>
> I have two plugins in pom.xml, when i try to use gradle init to
>   convert pom to gradle.build .  it seems those two plugins are not
>   converted to gradle.build successfully Is there any tools could
>   convert those maven plungs to gradle.build ?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/my.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/build_init_plugin.html#sec:pom_maven_conversion_), the Gradle `init` task does not parse the plugins part.

One reason behind that decision is there is no direct mapping from Maven plugins to Gradle plugins, and the size of the plugin ecosystem in both tools would make it hard to have such mapping when features might differ.